# Looping through multi-dimensional array to pre-populate dynamically generated form

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I am trying to create an ecommerce site. I have products that have different attributes (e.g. colour) and each of these needs to have their own model number and price etc,.

I have generated a form to gather this information and save it. However, I want to be able to save this info as a `$_SESSION` variable while users are adding products, so that they can come back to the price section and the form will be pre-populated with what they previously entered even though they haven't actually saved the product to the DB yet.

To do this I have a string that I treat as an array of items stored as a `$_SESSION` variable in PHP in the following format:

```
'item-test,100,20,20,20,20,£,1,item-test,100,20,20,20,20,£,2'
```

I parse this into an actual array I can deal with like so (when it gets to actually saving the product my SQL query is inside this `foreach()` loop):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['price_array'])){
    $price_array = $_SESSION['price_array'];
    $result = explode("item-",$price_array);
        foreach($result as $item){
        if(isset($item) && $item!=""){
            $itemValue = explode(",",$item);
            
            $product_model_no = $itemValue[0];
            $product_value = $itemValue[1];
            $product_discount = $itemValue[2];
            $product_margin = $itemValue[3];
            $product_shipping_domestic = $itemValue[4];
            $product_shipping_other = $itemValue[5];
            $product_currency = $itemValue[6];
            $product_attribute = $itemValue[7];
        }
    }
}
```

So to generate this form I've another loop that goes through all of the possible attributes (not all products might come in all colours so only the ones stored in the `$_SESSION` apply). If I try to pre-populate this as it is my variables above only have the values for the last item in the array.

However if I nest this inside the other loop it will get the correct data but it will generate the form a number of times depending on how many items are in the array, with each iteration of the form having the values for that item in the array.

I know this is very convoluted to try explain and I can't really provide all my code because it is very complex and most of it is generated in PHP from other information in other locations.

### Edit

The basics of how the form is being generated inside the other loop is as follows:

```
$params = [$attribute];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM attributes WHERE id=?";
$attributeResult = DB::run($sql,$params);
foreach ($attributeResult as $value) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 15; $i++) {                  
        //generate form here
        if($i == $product_attribute){
            // pre-populate form here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: we really need to see that other loop

Comment: @delboy1978uk thanks for your comment. Please see my edit

Comment: The top loop. Does it go where the generate form or populate form comment is?

Comment: @delboy1978uk at the moment it is where I have `//generate form here` but obviously that is only picking up the last item in the array

Comment: Yes, you overwrite each value with each iteration of the loop, before moving on. Can you see?

Comment: If I nest the second loop inside the first one it will get the correct values but it will generate the form once with the first array item populated and the second item will be blank, then generate the form again with the second item populated and the first item blank.

Comment: @delboy1978uk yeah I know whats happening. I was hoping to try find a way to get around this. I was looking up the `in_array()` function but this won't work for me as some of the other values in each item might also match

Comment: I was thinking I might have to put another counter variable inside the first loop and concat that to the variable names so each variable name is different  and then loop through all of these again inside the second loop - would this make sense?

Comment: I also considered putting `if($product_attribute == $i){break;}` inside the first loop which would work and do what I want but I also have a currency in there so some of our suppliers give us prices in £ and others in € and some in both. So this would work for a product where the prices are in one currency and we do the exchange ourselves but for products that have suppliers that give prices in both currencies we would have two items in the array with the same attribute but it will have different values, like I said it is rather complex and convoluted